# angularjs ng-if not working in Form

Tags: angularjs

I am trying using `ng-if` in my HTML

HTML

```
<td width=15% ng-if="value == I">Decision</td>  
<td width=10% ng-if="value != I">Status</td>
```

JS

```
    $scope.value = "I";
```

I am getting `$scope.value` value in my HTML. But `ng-if` not working.

More infomation please lookout http://jsfiddle.net/n3xWB/1493/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ng-hide` instead of `ng-if` and also you missed the quotes " 'I' "

```
<td width=15% ng-hide="value == 'I'">Decision</td>  
<td width=10% ng-hide="value != 'I'">Status</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

missed the quote around the `ng-if` values

```
<td width=15% ng-if="value == 'I'">Decision</td>  
<td width=10% ng-if="value != 'I'">Status</td>
```

```js
 
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("TodoCtrl",TodoCtrl )

 function TodoCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.value = "I";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
       <table>
        <tr>
           value =================== {{value}}
            <td width=15% ng-if="value == 'I'">Decision</td>  
           <td width=10% ng-if="value != 'I'">Status</td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```